# How to assign objects created into an array in different class

Tags: java, arrays, loops, object

I am a very new beginner at Java and trying to make an array that holds objects created from another class.

To break it down, I have a class called `TextBook`, which stores the title of the book, and `LibraryClass`, which has a `TextBook[] bookShelf` member variable. This member array is where the textbooks will be stored.

So I think what I need to do is:

```
public class LibraryClass
{
    private TextBook[] bookShelf;

    public static void main(TextBook[] args, int x) {
        TextBook [] bookShelf = new TextBook[x];
        for(int i=0;i<bookShelf.length;i++)
        {
            bookShelf[i] = TextBook[];
        }
        }
```

`bookShelf[i] = TextBook[];` is where I am stuck. The new textbook objects created will come out like `textBook1`, `textBook2`, `textBook3` and so on. I need to somehow link `bookShelf[i]` to `textBook1,2,3` etc. but how??

Comment: `public static void main(TextBook[] args, int x) ` - is it allowed ?

Comment: @Rehman `main` can be overloaded. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3759315/can-we-overload-the-main-method-in-java).

Comment: so are you saying my main is wrong? the int x was supposed to be a single parameter which determines how many number of textbooks the bookshelf could hold

Comment: Step one - create an array that can hold TextBook objects. Correct. Step two - create those TextBook objects. Wrong syntax there; it should simply read `bookShelf[i] = new TextBook()`; assuming that your TextBook class has a constructor going without arguments.

Comment: Was there a problem with my answer that caused you to not accept it?

Answer (score 1):

`bookShelf[i] = new TextBook();` instead of `bookShelf[i] = TextBook[];` assuming your TextBook class had a no args constructor.

This is how you create a new object `new` is a necessary keyword for this, and calling `TextBook()` will call the constructor of the object.

Every index in the array will have a new TextBook object.

These objects can be accessed with `bookShelf[i]` where `i` is the index of the object you are trying to access.